# MySQL: Using the value of two columns to calculate a third

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is a common question but I can't find a solution for it in the way I'm describing. My query is like this:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT SUM(finance_transaction_components.invoiced_price) 
        FROM finance_transactions
        JOIN finance_transaction_components ON finance_transaction_components.transaction_id = finance_transactions.id
        JOIN agents ON agents.id = finance_transactions.agent_id
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(finance_transactions.completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29"
    ) AS "Total Costs",

    (
        SELECT SUM(finance_transactions.agent_price)
        FROM finance_transactions
        JOIN agents ON agents.id = finance_transactions.agent_id
        WHERE finance_transactions.product_id != 10
        AND DATE_FORMAT(completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29" 
    ) AS "Total Revenue",

    (
        SELECT SUM(finance_transactions.agent_price)
        FROM finance_transactions
        JOIN agents ON agents.id = finance_transactions.agent_id
        WHERE finance_transactions.product_id != 10
        AND DATE_FORMAT(completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29" 
        AND IF(finance_transactions.lldrg > 0, IF(finance_transactions.lldrg = 1, 0, 1) ,1) = 1
    ) - ( SELECT SUM(finance_transaction_components.invoiced_price) 
        FROM finance_transactions
        JOIN finance_transaction_components ON finance_transaction_components.transaction_id = finance_transactions.id
        JOIN agents ON agents.id = finance_transactions.agent_id
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(finance_transactions.completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29"
    )   AS "Margin"

FROM finance_transactions
GROUP BY finance_transactions.agent_id
```

It doesn't really matter what the columns are etc. in this case, the important bit is this: **the *Margin* column needs to repeat the *Total Costs* and *Total Revenue* queries to calculate, which seems like a silly way of doing it.** But apparently I can't just say `"Total Revenue" - "Total Costs" AS "Margin`.

Comment: I see you just removed the aggregates functions. How will you link revenues and costings if more than one line is returned for each subquery ?

Comment: Sorry, I've now rollbacked the edit. I thought I could simplify the question for other readers by editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing without repeating code simply by using an inner query:

```
SELECT TotalCosts, TotalRevenue, TotalCost - TotalRevenue AS Margin
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT SUM(finance_transaction_components.invoiced_price) 
        FROM finance_transactions
        JOIN finance_transaction_components ON finance_transaction_components.transaction_id = finance_transactions.id
        JOIN agents ON agents.id = finance_transactions.agent_id
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(finance_transactions.completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29"
    ) AS TotalCosts,

    (
        SELECT SUM(finance_transactions.agent_price)
        FROM finance_transactions
        JOIN agents ON agents.id = finance_transactions.agent_id
        WHERE finance_transactions.product_id != 10
        AND DATE_FORMAT(completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29" 
    ) AS TotalRevenue
) t
```

**EDIT**: This answer is based on the first version of the question, the one with the aggregates functions.

Comment: This answer addresses the question at hand very well.  However, the best approach for this specific case (as originally stated) is to avoid making extra subqueries in the first place.

Comment: I agree with you, I didn't try to simplify it. In this particular case, your answer is way better.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**  - This answer is based on the query from the original question.

As @X.L.Ant has proposed, you can wrap the query and do the simple math in the wrapper query.  However, in your scenario, you can do this even more efficiently if you just simplify your query down to this:

```
SELECT agent_id, TotalCost, TotalRevenue, TotalRevenue - TotalCost AS Margin
FROM (
    SELECT finance_transactions.agent_id
           SUM(finance_transaction_totals.total_cost) AS TotalCost,
           SUM(CASE WHEN finance_transactions.product_id = 10 THEN 0 
                    ELSE finance_transactions.agent_price) AS TotalRevenue 
    FROM finance_transactions
    JOIN (SELECT transaction_id, SUM(invoiced_price) AS total_cost
          FROM finance_transaction_components
          GROUP BY transaction_id) finance_transaction_totals
       ON finance_transactions.id = finance_transaction_totals.transaction_id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(finance_transactions.completed_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-29"
    GROUP BY finance_transactions.agent_id 
) t
```